# Trying to store the output of a cmdlet to a variable

Tags: windows, powershell, scripting, powershell-3.0

I am trying to read in the last line of a log file and parse it for a particular piece of information.  The log file is a .csv and I need the number that is present in the third field.

```
while (1)
{ 
  Get-Content -Path C:\Users\alk6842\Desktop\logss.txt -Tail 1 -Wait | Foreach {($_ -split ',',4)[2]} | Foreach {($_ -split ' ',3)[1]}
}
```

This works to out put it to the screen, however I want to store the number in a variable or as an element in an array so I can work with it.  I've tried doing

```
while (1)
{ 
  $a = Get-Content -Path C:\Users\alk6842\Desktop\logss.txt -Tail 1 -Wait | Foreach {($_ -split ',',4)[2]} | Foreach {($_ -split ' ',3)[1]}
  $a
}
```

but this does not output anything.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that something is still writing to `logss.txt`, so `Get-Content` never completes, and thus the script never proceeds to echoing `$a`.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the `-Tail 1 -Wait` option? It means that the pipeline will never complete, and if the pipeline doesn't complete, it will forever to assign something to `$a`.

If you want to process it and use `-Wait`, process within a `Foreach-object` block:

```
Get-Content -Path C:\Users\alk6842\Desktop\logss.txt -Tail 1 -Wait | 
ForEach-Object {
    $first = ($_ -split ',',4)[2];
    $second = ($_ -split ' ',3)[1]
    #do whatever processing you want
}
```